# Android Studio Scrollbar in Code Editor

Tags: android, android-studio

Is there an option to make the scrollbar more visible in Android Studio? It looks very faint and thin.

All google searchs lead to Scrollbar view, and not the Studio Editor Scrollbar

Comment: That may be platform-specific. On my Ubuntu Linux machine, with Android Studio 2.1.3, the scrollbars are normal-sized.